# Hilt - app cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-hilt

This is my hilt module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(app: App) =
        Room.databaseBuilder(app, AppDatabase::class.java, "app_database").build()

    @Provides
    fun provideUserDao(database: AppDatabase) = database.userDao()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(): ContactsService {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(
                Moshi.Builder().build()))
            .build()
            .create(ContactsService::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRepository(api:ContactsService,dao: ContactsDao): ContactRepository{
        return ContactRepositoryImpl(api,dao)
    }
}
```

This is the indicated App class:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application() {
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
 ..\assignment\App_HiltComponents.java:128: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] com.example.assignment.App cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
```

I double check every class that I use injection and in each of them I used @Inject annotation. I read every stack question but none of them solved my problem.

Comment: Change `fun provideDatabase(app: App)`  to `fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext context: Context)` and `Room.databaseBuilder(context,  ...`

Comment: @jane the normal name doesn't work because 1, your App class has no constructor annotated with `@Inject`.  But even if it did, it wouldn't work properly because injection by default creates new instances of variables.  The Application class should only be constructed by the Framework as it's a Context.  So even if you did make it work, it wouldn't be the actual Application object and using it as such would be broken

Comment: Basically, Context objects have special rules because they can't be instantiated outside of the Android OS

Answer (score 2):

Hilt is built on top of the DI library Dagger. Dagger works only with a specific type of class.

Hilt provides @ApplicationContext as Context type.

You should provide your `App` explicitly.

```
@Provides
fun provideApp(@ApplicationContext context: Context): App = context as App
```